# Change 6.51 to 6.50 in java BigDecimal

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

Here it is what we have tried but none of those things work...

```
BigDecimal Total_Discount=new BigDecimal(10.00); 
BigDecimal Amount_To_User=new BigDecimal(00.00); 
BigDecimal Amount_To_Me=new BigDecimal(00.00);          

Amount_To_User=Total_Discount.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.65)).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); //65% of the amount
Amount_To_Me=Total_Discount.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.35)).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); //35% of the amount
```

> Dividing the values by % 65 and 35 so 10 will be 6.50 and 3.50 but i am getting 6.51 by using BigDecimal.DOWN i am getting 6.50 i have already values with 6.51 which i need to change to 6.50

```
Amount_To_User=Amount_To_User.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
System.out.println(Amount_To_User); //Gives the value 6.51
```

I want to change that 6.51 to 6.50 but this doesn't work

Comment: If you want to split the amount you should better only calculate one value by multiplication and the other by subtraction from your total account. In this case the formula `total = am_user + am_me` is satisfied.

Comment: DO NOT USE FLOATING POINT VALUES as values for Bigdecimals. Use integers or strings and e.g. `valueOf(int)` or `new BigDecimal(string)`. Stay away from floating point if you want the accuracy BigDecimals provide.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Use `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` as rounding Mode and/or use Strings as Input instead of double to create a BigDecimal.

**Explenation**

Compare the Documentation. Here is what you want:

> BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>
> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up. Behaves as for
>   ROUND_UP if the discarded fraction is ≥ 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for
>   ROUND_DOWN. **Note that this is the rounding mode that most of us were
>   taught in grade school**.

VS. what you have used.

> BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING (in your case behaves like BigDecimal.ROUND_UP, see below)
>
> Rounding mode to round towards positive infinity. If the BigDecimal is
>   positive, behaves as for ROUND_UP; if negative, behaves as for
>   ROUND_DOWN. Note that this rounding mode never decreases the
>   calculated value.

You allways round up. and you have a number with decimal places to round because you use a double as Input to create your BigDecimal (see below for an example).

> BigDecimal.ROUND_UP
>
> Rounding mode to round away from zero. Always increments the digit
>   prior to a nonzero discarded fraction. Note that this rounding mode
>   never decreases the magnitude of the calculated value.

In Addition you should create your BigDecimals from String input not from double. Use quotes `"` on the value in the Constructor.

```
BigDecimal total_Discount = new BigDecimal("10.00");
BigDecimal amount_To_User = new BigDecimal("00.00");
BigDecimal amount_To_Me = new BigDecimal("00.00");

amount_To_User = total_Discount.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.65")).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
amount_To_Me = total_Discount.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.35")).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(amount_To_User); //6.50
System.out.println(amount_To_Me); //3.50
```

This will show you why:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.65));
//prints 0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.65"));
//prints 0.65
```

A Double has not a perfect precision on every decimal digit while a String has it.

Comment: This is an interesting comment about Strings and Doubles.  I'm curious if there is a performance factor as well?  The string just gives you digits, while the Double seems to actually perform some sort of operation to convert a Double to a BigDecimal, which seems as if a String would be faster...  I wonder if this is the case for a lot of things.